# ComboBox return Selected Value Null while setting TextFormatString as "{0},{1}" in DevExpress?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I need to search both the columns in my dropdown eg:Code & Description, if I enter text it will search in both of my columns.How to do this in ASPx ComboBox?

I have given `TextFormatString="{0},{1}"` Search is working but returns Null in `SelectedItem.Value`. How to Solve this?

My Code:

```
<dxe:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbCurrencyGuarDetails" SkinID="ComboBoxList" 
                  runat="server" Width="100%" 
                  ClientInstanceName="cmbCurrencyGuarDetails" 
                  DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 
                  ValueType="System.String" 
                  TextFormatString="{0},{1}"
                  EnableCallbackMode="true" 
                  IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains"
                  CallbackPageSize="100">
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should set [ValueField](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_ValueFieldtopic). On client side you can get value directly using `cmbCurrencyGuarDetails.GetValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

As i suspected about your markup you have set the [ValueField Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_ValueFieldtopic)

> If the **EnableIncrementalFiltering** property is enabled, the value typed
>   by the end-user into the edit box is searched within the editor's
>   list, based upon the TextFormatString property's defined format.
>
> If the editor's ASPxComboBox.ValueField property is not defined, the
>   text value formatted using the [**TextFormatString**](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsComboBoxProperties_TextFormatStringtopic) property is used
>   as the editor's value.

e.g.

```
 <dxe:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbCurrencyGuarDetails" SkinID="ComboBoxList" 
                      runat="server" Width="100%" 
                      ClientInstanceName="cmbCurrencyGuarDetails" 
                      DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 
                      ValueType="System.String" 
                      TextFormatString="{0},{1}"
                      EnableCallbackMode="true" 
                      IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains"
                      ValueField="CustomerID" /// If object data source then mention property here
                      CallbackPageSize="100">
```

References:
[DevExpress ASPxComboBox not filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305270/devexpress-aspxcombobox-not-filtering)

Comment: No i have given the Value Field, the problem is in ComboBox DisplayText is like Code,Description. i need to display Description alone. Without changing TextFormatString="{0},{1}"
If i change this to TextFormatString="{1}" then my search will not work.

Comment: Have you checked the reference link and the textformatstring property for the appropriate implementation with multiple column data source??

Answer (score 0):

You can take selected value with;

```
cmbCurrencyGuarDetails.Value
```

and if u didnt add ValueField at server side u must add

```
<dxe:ASPxComboBox ValueField="ID"  ... >
```